# Reproduce the \texttrademark function

Tags: symbols

Is there a way of emulating/reproducing the `\texttrademark` function with exactly the same output in font and dimensions terms?

Note that `\textsuperscript{TM}` results in a different output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}
    \textsuperscript{TM} or \texttrademark
\end{document}
```

> [image: superscript(TM) or textrademark()]

I'm interested in reproducing a function that does the same as `\texttrademark`, but not `textsuperscript{TM}`, since both have different representations.

Comment: your question isn't clear, same output as what? same as the other text or same as the current definition of texttrademark (which is font encoding dependent, but you have not said what font encoding you are using). It might help if you made a complete small (4 or 5 line) document and stated what output you get and what output you want to get

Comment: You seem to have a serife font in the first TM and a serifeless font in the second one. I don't understand your question actually

Comment: What's the problem in using `\texttrademark`?

Comment: @egreg There is no problem using `\texttradermark`. I just want a function that emulates its output.

Comment: @AlberteRomero In the sense that it uses a similar font shape with different characters than “T” and ”M”?

Comment: @egreg Yes, that's it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might use the Fetamont fonts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{fetamont}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\simtm}[1]{%
  \textsuperscript{\normalfont\ffmfamily\fontseries{lc}\selectfont#1}%
}

\begin{document}
A\texttrademark\quad
A\simtm{TM}\quad
A\simtm{ABC}
\end{document}
```

that gives (the first for comparison)

[image]

Comment: (+1) for (somehow) divining the question.

Comment: @cfr Probably the most accurate (and most entertaining) description of the situation. :)

Comment: @SeanAllred My crystal ball was working well.

Comment: I've gotta get me one of those…

Answer (score 0):

Just switch fonts in a group:

```
\newcommand\myTM{{\normalfont\texttrademark}}
```

If you are switching actual types (font families, e.g. Times vs. Computer Modern) within your document, you will need to specify the font fully.

Comment: maybe `\normalfont` better than `\rmfamily` ? But who knows, unclear questions don't have good answers...

Comment: @tohecz "Unclear questions..." Yeah, that's my thought too. But I suppose `\normalfont` would bring the size down, which seems unreasonable of put in a `\large` context, for instance.

Comment: `> \normalfont =\long macro: ->\usefont \encodingdefault \familydefault \seriesdefault \shapedefault \relax ` It doesn't change the size

Comment: @tohecz Whoops, my mistake.  Edited FWIW.